# Ruby + Nokogiri + Xpath navigate Node_Set

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

```
<Item id="item0">
  <Links>
    <FirstLink id="link1" target="one"/>
    <SecondLink id="link2" target="two"/>
  </Links>
  <Data>
    <String>content</String>
  </Data>
</Item>
<Item id="item1">
  <Links>
    <FirstLink id="link1" target="two"/>
    <SecondLink id="link2" target="two"/>
  </Links>
  <Data>
    <String>content</String>
  </Data>
</Item>
```

I have created a Nokogiri-NodeSet with this structure, i.e. a list of items with links and data children.
How can I filter any items that don't match a certain value in the 'target'-attribute of `<FirstLink>`?

Actually, what I want in the end is to extract the `<Data><String>`-Content of every `<Item>` that matches a certain value in it's `<FirstLink>` "Target"-Attribute.

I've tried several approaches already but I'm at a loss as to how to identify an element by an attribute of it's grandchild, then extracting the content of this grandchild's parent's sibling, X(.

Comment: Just give an expected output also...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can build up an XPath expression to do this. Assuming we are starting from the whole XML document, rather than the node-set you already have, something like

```
//Item
```

will select all `<Item>` elements (I’m guessing you already have something like that to get this node-set).

Next, to select only those `<Item>` elements which have `<Links><FirstLink>` where `FirstLink` has a `target` attribute value of `one`:

```
//Item[Links/FirstLink[@target='one']]
```

and finally to select the `Data/String` children of those nodes:

```
//Item[Links/FirstLink[@target='one']]/Data/String
```

So with Nokogiri you could use something like this (where `doc` is your parsed document):

```ruby
doc.xpath("//Item[Links/FirstLink[@target='one']]/Data/String")
```

or if you want to use the node-set you already have you can use a relative expression:

```ruby
nodeset.xpath("self::Item[Links/FirstLink[@target='one']]/Data/String")
```

Comment: Great, just what I looked for, thank you. And in an easy to follow step-by-step way,:D. I think I need to familiarize myself more with the possibilities in XPath. I tried, but I simply couldn't wrap my head around how to formulate an expression like yours for my case.

Answer (score 1):

I completely didn't understand what your goal is. But using a guess, I am trying to show you, how to proceed in this case :

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML <<-xml
<Item id="item0">
  <Links>
    <FirstLink id="link1" target="one"/>
    <SecondLink id="link2" target="two"/>
  </Links>
  <Data>
    <String>content1</String>
  </Data>
</Item>
<Item id="item1">
  <Links>
    <FirstLink id="link1" target="two"/>
    <SecondLink id="link2" target="two"/>
  </Links>
  <Data>
    <String>content2</String>
  </Data>
</Item>
xml
```

[`#xpath`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-xpath) method with the expression `"//Item"`, will select all the `Item` nodes. Then those `Item` nodes will be passed to the [`#reject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reject) method to select only those nodes, that has a node called `Links` having the `target` attribute value is `"one"`. If any of the links, either `FirstLink` or `SecondLink` has the `target` attribute value `"one"`, for that nodes grandparent node `Item` will be selected.

`node.at("//Links/FirstLink")['target']` will give you the string say `"one"` which is a value of **target** attribute of the node, **FirstLink** of first **Item** nodes , then `"two"` from the second **Item** node. The part `['any vaue']` in `node.at("//Links/FirstLink")['target']['any vaue']` is a call to the [`String#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) method.

**Remember** below approach will give you the *flexibility of the use regular expression* too.

```
nodeset = doc.xpath("//Item").reject do |node|
  node.at("//Links/FirstLink")['target']['any vaue']
end
```

Now `nodeset` contains only the required `Item` nodes. Now I use [#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map), passing each *item* node inside it to collect the content of the `String` node. Then [`#at`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at) method with an expression `//Data/String`, will select the `String` node. Then [`#text`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-text), will give you the *content* of each **String** node.

```
nodeset.map { |n| n.at('//Data/String').text } # => ["content1"]
```